# "Child-proof" storage for Minecraft multiplayer?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

**The Situation**

I am playing multiplayer Minecraft on PS3 with my young child, who loves to craft new things from the easy console version crafting interface.

Sometimes I leave for a mining session, to find when returning to our house that my kid has created a dozen golden shovels, or diamond helmets.

**The Questions**

Is there a way to get back the rare ingredients for those crafted items?

Do you have suggestions to store rare items in a location not easily accessible to other players (but still relatively easily accessible to me, an experienced player)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way to do this would be to create an ender chest, this chest is separate for each player, meaning only you can see the items that you have placed inside.

Although, this does mean that your kid could put items in the chest that you wouldn't be able to see, so just make sure that you put all of your rare items into the chest.

[image: crafting recipe]

wiki page: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Chest

Answer (score 3):

That's the only reason why hidden storage contraptions are made.

For instance this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/9ZVrBTQqEsg?t=126).

redstone torch is used to power the sticky piston which then moves the block over the chest. this reveals the chest. you can access the chest. When you want to hide it again, simply break the redstone torch.

just make sure that you open the secret chest when no one is near by you.